# Can I publish to a specific subscription in a SNS topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

When I publish to a topic it hits ALL subscribers ALWAYS?

I have a topic with several subscriptions, sometimes I want to publish a message to just one of those subscriptions.

Is there a way to do this or do I need to create another topic and have the subscription in 2 topics? In that case I'm bugging the user (assuming this use case is to message users) twice right?

Comment: Don't think there is a way to do that. It's like a mailing list.

Comment: When you write "to just one", do you mean one in particular or that the message is only processed by one subscriber? For the former, you could embed something in the message that the subscribers can check before processing/ignoring the message. The latter is more a queue use case.

Comment: you mean like messages attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes -- when a message is sent to an Amazon SNS topic, **all subscribers receive the message**.

If you wish to contact a specific subscriber, your code will have to contact them directly (eg via email).

Amazon SNS also has the ability to [send an SMS message to one or more recipients](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SMSMessages.html) without using an SNS Topic. So, if your desired recipients are on SMS, this is a simple task.

Comment: I was also wondering if maybe I could do this with a policy or filters? Or am I misunderstanding what those features are for? Could I define a policy to only send to one subscriber based on message attributes or something?

Comment: When a message is sent to an Amazon SNS topic, all subscribers receive the message.